# After update typescript ^3.7.2 to latest "typescript": "^4.4.4" - error TS2339: Property 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have used this msSaveOrOpenBlob method . its was working properly but after update typescript into latest version I am getting multiple error there is two error .

> window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, filename);

> error TS2322: Type 'Promise<>' is not assignable to type 'IPromise<>'.

What is the fix of that .

Answer (score 42):

[@Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69682484/823732) answer is correct, but if you just want to get around the issue - since you are using TypeScript - you can just cast it to type `any` before calling msSaveOrOpenBlob.

`(window.navigator as any).msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, filename);`

Also, you should make sure the navigator object does have the method in the first place, so:

```ts
const nav = (window.navigator as any);
if (nav.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  nav.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, filename);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`msSaveOrOpenBlob` was a proprietary addition to the `Navigator` object, added by Microsoft for Internet Explorer. Since Microsoft is phasing out support for Internet Explorer, it has removed support for many of the non-standard additions made to the lib.dom.d.ts and lib.es*.d.ts files that ship with TypeScript. See [this GitHub issue about the changes to the DOM.d.ts file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029).

As indicated in [this GitHub issue on the subject](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45612), you will have to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add these types to `Navigator` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's my first development in angular more specific in the 12 version, and I created a method in a component that does a download a xlsx file, in Chrome its work but in IE it doesn't work, I find that adding this line `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, filename);` Explorer can download file, but in VSC mark error and it is

> Property 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

and I change the module and lib in `tsconfig.json`,

```
"module": "es2020",
"lib": [
    "es2020",
    "dom"
]
```

to:

```
"module": "es2015",
"lib": [
    "es2015",
    "dom"
]
```

In the code `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` VSC mark the same

> Property 'msSaveOrOpenBlob'....'

but when I execute ng serve its work and download a xlsx file in IE and Chrome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This appears to be another question, or at least an "I'm having this problem too comment", as it certainly does not answer the question of how to get rid of the error... which is answered in my answer, with a workaround in the other answer.