# After update typescript typescript": "4.4.4" - have an error when try npm run build - Property 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: typescript

I have used this code:

`var navigator: Navigator; if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName); }`

But when i try to run - **npm run build** command i get ERROR: TS2339: Property 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

What i need to change in code?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69552023/215552) which unfortunately has no upvoted answers and therefore can't be used as a target. Basically, you need to pull the types from the historical DOM.d.ts and use declaration merging to add them back yourself. Those functions are only for use in Internet Explorer, a browser that is rapidly reaching its end of life.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After update typescript ^3.7.2 to latest "typescript": "^4.4.4" - error TS2339: Property 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552023/after-update-typescript-3-7-2-to-latest-typescript-4-4-4-error-ts2339)

Answer (score 0):

'**msSaveOrOpenBlob**' and '**msSaveBlob**' has been removed from Angular 13 (TypeScript v4.4)

Create a new file name **navigator.d.ts** and add following code in content

```
interface Navigator {
    msSaveOrOpenBlob: (blob: Blob) => void
    msSaveBlob?: (blob: any, defaultName?: string) => boolean
}
```

I don't think this is a solution, but a work around that worked for me.